# List duplicate files in a directory in Unix

Tags: file, unix, command

Is there any `unix` commands that can display `duplicate files` in a particular `directory`.kindly let me know your comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use [fdupes](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fdupes) to achieve this.

```
fdupes ./directory
```

That should list all the duplicate files in a directory, you can also pass it -r for a recursive scan into subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

fdupe is a great tool to do the job. I would also recommend [rmlint](https://rmlint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
For a Linux directory (ext4) of 60 GB of photos and videos:

- rmlint took 38 seconds to find duplicates and offer different clean up actions.
- fdupe took 56 seconds to find the duplicates.