# List all duplicate files in a filesystem given the root directory.

Tags: algorithm, performance, oop, hash, filesystems

How would you go about designing an algorithm to list all the duplicate files in a filesystem? My first thought it to use hashing but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it. Any possible design tradeoffs to keep in mind?

Comment: duplicate by name or by content?

Answer (score 2):

Hashing all your files will take a very long time because you have to read all the file contents.

I would recommend a 3-step algorithm:

1. scan your directories and note down the paths & sizes of the files
2. Hash only the files which have the same size as other files, only if there are more than 2 files with the same size: if a file has the same size as only one other file, you don't need the hashing, just compare their contents one-to-one (saves hashing time, you won't need the hash value afterwards)
3. Even if the hash is the same, you still have to compare the files byte-per-byte because hash can be identical for different files (although this is very unlikely if the file size is the same and it's *your* filesystem).

You could also do without hashing at all, opening all files at the same time if possible, and compare contents. That would save a multiple read on big files. There are a lot of tweaks that you could implement to save time depending on the type of your data (ex: if 2 compressed/tar files have the same size > x Ggigabytes size (and the same name), don't read the contents, given your process, the files are very likely to be duplicates)

That way, you avoid hashing files which size is unique in the system. Saves a lot of time.

Note: I don't take names into account here, because I suppose names can be different.

EDIT: I've done a bit of research (too late) and found out that `fdupes` seems to do exactly that if you are using Un*x-like systems:

https://linux.die.net/man/1/fdupes

seen in that question: [List duplicate files in a directory in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321509/list-duplicate-files-in-a-directory-in-unix)